# Variable not being assigned and called correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get a picture from my files to print after the user input a number for PokeID in the interactive manual. But when the number is entered it does not run into file_type. I do not know if I am calling it correctly. StackOverflow is telling me to add more details but I do not know what else to say. Why is the user input not running into the file?

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, Image, clear_output
from IPython.display import Image, Audio
from ipywidgets import interact_manual
import glob
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

display(HTML("<h1> Ud's <font color= 'red'>PokeDex</font> </h1>"))
pokedexpic = "https://img.icons8.com/color/480/pokedex.png"
display(Image(url=pokedexpic, width=200))
display(Audio(filename="pokesong.mp3"))

url='http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all'

website = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(website.content)

tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

col=[]
i=0

for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    col.append((name,[]))

for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    T=tr_elements[j]
    
    if len(T)!=10:
        break
    
    i=0
    
    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content() 
        if i>0:
            try:
                data=int(data)
            except:
                pass
        col[i][1].append(data)
        i+=1
        
Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)

src_path = "/home/jovyan/library/ist256/spring2022/lessons/Project/PokeImages/"
no_of_image_to_show = 1 

@interact_manual(Pokemon = df['Name'])
def main(Pokemon):
    print(df[  df['Name'] == Pokemon ])

    @interact_manual(PokeID = "") #PokeID wont run into file_type to print png
    def main(PokeID):
        file_type = f"{PokeID}.png"  
        
def display_n_images(src_path, file_type, no_of_image_to_show):
    image_folder = glob.glob(src_path + file_type)
    image_folder = image_folder[0:no_of_image_to_show]

    for a_image in image_folder:
        display(Image(filename=a_image))
        print(a_image)
        
display_n_images(src_path, file_type, no_of_image_to_show)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you are interacting with `file_type` incorrectly. You refer to it outside of the inner function `main`, where this variable is defined as local. The minimum change required for your code to work is to declare `file_type` as a global variable.

```py
...

@interact_manual(Pokemon = df['Name'])
def main(Pokemon):
    display(df[  df['Name'] == Pokemon ])

    @interact_manual(PokeID = "") 
    def main(PokeID):
        global file_type     # make file_type available globally
        file_type = f"{PokeID}.png" 
        print(file_type)
...
```